# adb command - Marshmallow - change preferred network mode LTE/GSM

Tags: database, sqlite, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am on the 6.0.1 Marshmallow OS and my previous commands to change the preferred network mode are no longer working.

Commands used in Kit Kat worked without issue:

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "SELECT * FROM global WHERE name='preferred_network_mode'"
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "update global SET value=1 WHERE name='preferred_network_mode'"
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "select value FROM secure WHERE name='preferred_network_mode'
```

Commands from above entered in this OS result in output:

```
Error: no such table: global
```

I pulled the database file, which was completely empty:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/
```

Is there any ADB command that I can use to change the preferred_network_mode to LTE/GSM?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311920/2673792 for best solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of research, this was the working solution I found for **Marshmallow**.

The Preferred Network Mode numbers are found:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/ril/+/master/include/telephony/ril.h#228

1 is GSM Only

11 is LTE Only

```
adb wait-for-devices
adb root
adb wait-for-devices
adb shell settings list global | grep pref
```

This returned to me both "preferred_network_mode" and "preferred_network_mode1"

```
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode 1
adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode1 1
adb shell stop ril-daemon
adb shell start ril-daemon
```

Comment: after stop ril-daemon , start ril-daemon don't work :( any advice?

Comment: @r1si its not immediate, is this solution not working at all for you?

Comment: @r1si Same as you, after restarting ril-daemon, the preferred_network_mode is reversed to the original, however I found toggling  aeroplane mode on and off is working. :)

Answer (score 1):

For setting RAT on SUB1, run below command:

```
adb wait-for-devices

adb root

adb wait-for-devices

adb remount

adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode 1

adb shell settings put global preferred_network_mode1 1

adb shell stop ril-daemon

adb shell start ril-daemon

adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1

adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true

adb shell sleep 5;

adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0

adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
```

Now, check if RAT is set or not by running below command:

```
adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep mServiceState
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311920/2673792 for full solution

Answer (score -1):

adb shell:

```
content update --uri content://settings/global --bind value:i:12 --where "name='preferred_network_mode'"
```

12 == LTE + WCDMA, for more see ril.h

dont forget to set preferred_network_mode1 and preferred_network_mode2 and preferred_network_mode3